# Eclipse - Kotlin

Tags: eclipse, class, kotlin, compiler-errors

im trying to learn Kotlin using Eclipse. The problem i have is, that when i try to run my Code, i get the following error message:

```
Plug-in "org.eclipse.jdt.launching" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.JavaSourceLookupDirector".
Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 53
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/debug/core/sourcelookup/AbstractSourceLookupDirector.dispose()V @29: goto
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b801 f9b6 01fa 4c2b 2ab9 022c 0200 2b2a
    0000010: b902 2e02 002a b401 d6b6 01ef 4ea7 0018
    0000020: 2db9 021b 0100 c001 004d 2c2a a500 092c
    0000030: b902 3a01 002d b902 1a01 009a ffe5 2ab4
    0000040: 01d6 b601 eb2a b401 dbc6 0026 2ab4 01db
    0000050: 593a 05be 3604 033e a700 1119 051d 324d
    0000060: 2cb9 0234 0100 8403 011d 1504 a1ff ef2a
    0000070: 01b5 01db 2a01 b501 d7b1
```

I have tried to clean up the project, and update everything.

my code im writing:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: Can I make a small suggestion? Intellij IDEA supports Kotlin very well, both come from the same company. Maybe just give it a try?

Comment: @Twistleton The Kotlin Eclipse plugin is also from the same company, who then decided to support Kotlin by their own IDE only. So, Kotlin is not vendor neutral. [If you don't want to be trapped in vendor lockdown, better stay away from it](https://twitter.com/_Pyves/status/1314276928279511040). And by the way, this kind of ads/suggestions is not wanted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @howlger I didn't want to advertise, that's why I phrased the suggestion very carefully. I know that recommendations are usually not appropriate. Of course, you can also work very well with Eclipse.

Comment: @Twistleton It would be state of the art to provide a language server. JetBrains decided against it for political and not technical reasons. And for example, Kotlin works with JetBrains null annotations polluting the bytecode and not with Eclipse JDT null annotations not polluting the bytecode. From your comment not mentioned any of this, I can't tell whether you are being paid by JetBrains or not.

Answer (score 2):

I have had exactly the same issue, but I need to import and start Kotlin project, so uninstalling Kotlin plugin is not an option.

My setup: Eclipse 2021-03 + Kotlin Plugin 0.8.21.

I found a solution that worked for me here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=567081

Installing latest AspectJ Development Tools (today it is 2.2.4) helped me to solve the issue.